# In reactnative expo I tried using secureStore from expo in redux to save token the one I get from api

Tags: react-native, api, react-redux

I tried using redux to save token the one I get from `api` in react native  ..its working now.
First one is for settoken and other one is for gettoken.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUFY6.jpg)

```js
export const verifyOTP = (formValues, actions) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(startSubmitting());
    const url = `/validate-otp`;

    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("mobile", formValues.mobile);
    formdata.append("otp", formValues.otp);
    const response = await api.post(url, formdata);
    

    dispatch({
      type: "VERIFY_OTP",
      payload: response,
    });
    dispatch(stopSubmitting());
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("userToken", response.data.access_token);
  };
};

export const checkUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userToken");
    const url = `/me`;
    const response = await api
      .post(url, { token })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error.response;
      });

    dispatch({
      type: "CHECK_USER",
      payload: response,
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: How it is not working? and did you tried setting the token within `.then` scope?

Comment: you havent saved your token in any variable.

Comment: can u say in which line the variable should be written? @Aadi

Comment: otp validation is sucessfully done but in CheckUser function it showing that checkeduser  is not authorised it gives status 401 error @ShoaibKhan

Comment: can you put what error or what is the output your getting in you back-end console?

Comment: Have you tried this in POSTMAN?

Comment: yes tried on postman working perfectly fine @Aadi

Comment: Can you provide your front-end code if you have written and edit your question?

Comment: yes i have added the  error link see the first line
"enter image description here"  @Aadi

Comment: don't need JSON.stringify

Comment: Maybe you're missing something in headers like `Content-Type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

you are mixing two different implementations in `checkUser` to handle a promise which is clearly incorrect and leads to the issues.

##### The Solution

since your other parts of codes use the `async/await` so try to remove `then/catch` block from the `response` constant:

```
const checkUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const url = '/me';
    try {
      const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsycn("userToken);
      const response = await api.post(url, {token})
      
      dispatch({type: "CHECK_USER", payload: response})
    } catch (error) {
      // to proper action on failure case
    }
  }
}
```

**Note 1:** always use `async/await` in `try/catch` block. more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#adding_error_handling) documentation.

##### Optional

since you are trying to call two async actions (once for getting token and once for calling '/me' API), I encourage you to use two different `try/catch` blocks to handle the failure case for each async action separately. for example:

```
const checkUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let token = null;
    
    try {
      token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userToken");
    } catch (err) {
      // proper action in case of failure on getting the token from storage
    }

   // you may need to ignore API calls without the token, so:
    try {
      if(token){
        const url = '/me';
        const response = await api.post(url, {token});
        dispatch({type: "CHECK_USER", payload: response});
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // take proper action with the error response according to your applicaiton
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's my pleasure @afshanazaman . is your issue solved with my answer?

Comment: actuallly i solved it before...but im stuck in detete token now

Comment: so you can create another question and ask about the problem @afshanazaman

Comment: yes created please check it

Comment: for the **current question and answer** : If your question is solved, please accept the solution. The ✔ is below the ▲/▼ arrow, at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the usefulness of an answer with the ▲/▼ arrow. Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question. more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you  @afshanazaman

Comment: I'm new here in stackoveflow..they said I need 15reputation to cast a vote @novonimo

Comment: Yes, for upvote you need to +15 rep, but you can accept the answer @afshanazaman